# why array.reduce returns NaN for no reason

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I simply do this:

```js
const ar = [1, 2, 3];
ar.reduce(Math.max, 0); // returns NaN
ar.reduce((a, c) => Math.max(a, c), 0); // returns 3 as expected
```

Any reason for this behaviour?

Comment: If you have a question about the behaviour of a method, consult the specification of the method. See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce.  Your question is answered by the first line of the specification: *"NOTE: callbackfn should be a function that takes four arguments."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Unmitigated has clearly explained what's going on in your code and has shown how to use `Array#reduce` and especially `Math#max`.

Here, I show you can use just `Math#max`:

```js
const 
      ar = [1, 2, 3],
      
      mx = Math.max(...ar);
      
console.log( mx );
```

Answer (score 3):

The callback function to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is passed 4 arguments: the accumulator, the current element, the index, and the original array. All of these end up being passed to `Math.max`.

The array itself cannot be converted to a number, so `Math.max` returns `NaN`.

`ar.reduce(Math.max, 0);` is essentially equivalent to the following code:

```js
const ar = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(ar.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
  console.log(acc, curr, i, arr); // only for demonstration
  return Math.max(acc, curr, i, arr);
}, 0));
```

`ar.reduce((a, c) => Math.max(a, c), 0)` uses only the arguments that it needs, so it works correctly.

Comment: Perhaps the author of the question wants to get the highest value in the array, right?

Comment: @XMehdi01 What does that have to do with the answer?

Comment: Your answer did not complete the required

Comment: @XMehdi01 No, the question asked for an explanation of why the result is `NaN` ("Any reason for this behaviour?"). The asker already knows how to get the correct result, as shown in this snippet in the question: `ar.reduce((a, c) => Math.max(a, c), 0);`. Nowhere is it asked how to get the maximum.

Comment: Yes you are right